# Want to echo variable, however no results are echoed

Tags: php, mysql

i receive "echo "Klaida!!!!"" meaning there is no results.
Could you please point out my mistake in code.

```
    $dezesdezesId = $_GET["dezesId"];
        $query        = "SELECT * FROM dezes WHERE dezesId = '$dezesdezesId'";
        $result       = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows ($result) > 0)
            {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $dezesPavadinimas = $row["pavadinimas"];
                    $dezesLikutis     = $row["likutis"];
                }


                echo $dezesLikutis;

            }

                    else
                    {
                        echo "Klaida!!!!" . mysqli_error($connection); 
                    }
```

Comment: Side note, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah, thanks man, but its just a sandbox test code..that doesnt work :)

Comment: It seems like the query simply doesn't find any matches. Without knowing the content of your DB or what `$_GET['dezesId']` contains, it's hard for us to know why it happens.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: ^^^ and you will also break your query if the input contains a single quote or ends with a backslash. So it's not only insecure, it might break the query with "harmless" inputs.

Answer (score 0):

echo this inside your while loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
                $dezesPavadinimas = $row["pavadinimas"];
                $dezesLikutis     = $row["likutis"];
                echo $dezesLikutis;
}
```

and try to use '{$dezesdezesId}' your variable inside your query string

Comment: That's not an answer to the OP's question, though.The first `ìf`-statement, `mysqli_num_rows ($result) > 0`, seems to return false so it doesn't even come to the while loop.

Comment: Think it does return false as well. Putting echo $dezesLikutis; inside while didnt help.